# ThreadPool of Threads executed inside a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Here is short program in which I have queries posted after the program

```java
public class ThreadCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadCheck threadCheck = new ThreadCheck();
        threadCheck.execute();
    }

    public void execute() {
        ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("my-thread-pool-%d").build();
        int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(availableProcessors, threadFactory);
        executor.execute(() -> executeThread());
        executor.execute(() -> executeThread());
        executor.execute(() -> executeThread());
    }

    private void executeThread() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()); // the name format is my-thread-pool-%d
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            // executing sub-Threads
            new Thread(() ->
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName())).start(); // the name format is Thread-%d
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
my-thread-pool-0
my-thread-pool-1
my-thread-pool-2
Thread-0
Thread-1
Thread-5
Thread-4
Thread-3
Thread-6
Thread-2
Thread-7
Thread-8
```

I wanted to execute my Threads and the sub-Threads created within the Thread using a particular ThreadPool. For that I have created a `ScheduledExecutorService` with a `ThreadFactory` having name format as **my-thread-pool-%d**. Since I am not executing my sub-Threads using the given ScheduledExecutorService, the sub-Threads names are of the format **Thread-%d**.

My question is, are these sub-Threads executed via the `ForkJoinPool` or via the ScheduledExecutorService since they are sub-Threads?

If the sub-Threads are not executed by the given ScheduledExecutorService, is there any way to execute them without even providing the `ExecutorService`.

Comment: The "sub-threads" as you call them are created with `new Thread`. They do not come out of any pool, they are new objects, with their underlying system resources. A pool simply contains already started threads that are shared among "clients" of the pool. I do not think there is a way to start a thread with `new` and still get it out of a pool.

Comment: Since you create your threads yourself with `new Thread()` and not with ThreadPools, then they are not part of any thread pools ;) There's no notion of sub-threads - just threads. You can create as many as you want manually, or you can ask Thread Pools to do that (and those pools will keep track of those threads that they created).

Comment: That was very helpful. Thank you both for your time.